# Is there some number in this sequence whose base $10$ representation ends with $2015$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Given a list of the positive integers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $...$, take the first three numbers $1$, $2$, $3$ and their sum $6$ and cross all four numbers off the list. Repeat with the three smallest remaining numbers $4$, $5$, $7$ and their sum $16$. Continue in this way, crossing off the three smallest remaining numbers and their sum and consider the sequence of sums produced: $6$, $16$, $27$, $36$, $\dots$. Is there some number in this sequence whose base $10$ representation ends with $2015$?

Comment: I'd start by writing a script to show me the first $100$ sums or so, in order to "get a feel" of the pattern.

Comment: $12015$ is in the list, so the answer is yes.

Comment: To provide a source this was problem B2 in this year's putnam exam

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sums, the sequence shows a period $\pmod{90}$. In particular, the series repeats the cycle $6,16,27,37,46,57,66,75,87 \pmod{90}$, occasionally showing $45$ or $47$ instead of $46 \pmod{90}$ (the first of these exceptions occurs at $227$). From this, we can directly get that the large majority of the numbers in the sequence of sums end with $6$ or $7$, and that the smaller proportion of numbers ending with $5$ is mostly given by numbers that are $\equiv 75\pmod{90}$. Also note that all numbers that are $\equiv 75\pmod{90}$ are contained in the sequence.  Thus, we can conclude that any number ending with the digits $2015$ is necessarily part of the sequence if it is $\equiv 75\pmod{90}$. It is not difficult to show that the first number of this kind is $42015$.

Interestingly, $12015$ is part of the sequence as well, since it corresponds to an exception of the type $45\pmod{90}$.

Comment: You have it backwards.  It should be that any number ending in 2105 that is in the sequence is $75 \bmod {90}$, (or maybe $45 \bmod {90}$).  You have not shown that any number ending in $2015$ and $\equiv 75 \bmod {90}$ is in the sequence.

Comment: @Ross: the sequence is periodic $\pmod {90}$, so that all numbers that are $\equiv 75 \pmod{90}$ must necessary be in the sequence, independently of their final digits. So the solution reduces to find at least one of these numbers ending with $2015$, such as $42015$. However, any other number $\equiv 75 \pmod{90}$ (with or without $2015$ as the final digits) is in the sequence.